# How to show the inequality with the matrix fraction?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, inequality, matrix-calculus

I'm working on a proof where one step is to show the following inequality
$$
{\rm tr}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_ix_i^\top\sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i}\right)^{-1}\right]
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i},
$$
where $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times 1}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_ix_i^\top$, and $p_i$'s are probabilities with $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$. It's easy to check that this inequality holds when $d=1$ by using Jensen inequality. I would like to ask how to show it for the high-dimensional case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if this helps but ${\rm tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_ix_i^\top\sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i{\rm tr}\left(x_ix_i^\top\right)\sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_i^\top x_i\sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i}$

Comment: Do we have any additional assumption on the $x_i$?  Are they unit vectors?  Also, is that exponent supposed to be on one side of the equation but not the other?

Comment: The claim is not true for arbitrary $x_i$'s. If the $x_i$ are scaled by a factor $\lambda$, the left-hand side scales like $\lambda^{-4}$, the right-hand side like $\lambda^2$.

Comment: @P.Quinton If the $x_i$ are unit vectors, then the claim would follow if only this exponent $-1$ were not there.

Comment: @daw Thanks for your comments. But I've checked there is no problem when scaling the $x_i$'s. Kindly note that the inverse of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ and the sqrt as well as exponent $-1$ of the trace help cancel out some $\lambda$, and both sides scale $1/\lambda$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your comment! No extra assumptions for $x_i$'s currently. And the $-1$ is not the exponent but the inverse of the matrix.

Comment: @P. Quinton Thanks for your comment! But the $-1$ indicates the inverse, I may not apply the equation directly.

Comment: @BobSavage Well, if you take the inverse of the right hand side of my equation then you get the $d=1$ case right ? I'm curious on how you proved it by the way.

Comment: @P. Quinton If $x_i$ is a scaler, we have $\mathbf{\Sigma}=\sum_ip_ix_i^2$ and hence $\sqrt{x_i^\top\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}x_i}=\frac{|x_i|}{\sum_ip_ix_i^2}$. Then we have $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_i^2\sqrt{x_i^2\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-2}}\right)^{-1}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{p_ix_i^2}{\sum_i p_ix_i^2}\right)|x_i|\right]^{-1}$. Note that $\frac{p_ix_i^2}{\sum_i p_ix_i^2}$ is a new probability, then applying the Jesen inequality and do the similar transformation on the right side of inequality, we can prove it holds finally.

Comment: You can always edit your own question. In you are using the MSE website (I'm not sure about the mobile app), there should be a group of links `share cite edit delete flag` in grey just below the  tags of your question. You may click `edit` to edit.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your reminder and help. Actually, I'm new here and not familiar with some buttons. :)

Answer (score 1):

*(Edit. The OP has clarified that the LHS of the inequality is the trace of a matrix inverse rather than the inverse of a matrix trace. So, this answer does not address the OP, but I'll leave it here if anyone find it useful. )*

Your proof of the scalar case can be extended to higher dimensions. Since
$$
\sum_i \frac1d\ p_i x_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i
= \frac1d\operatorname{tr}\left(\Sigma^{-1} \sum_i p_ix_ix_i^T\right)
= \frac1d\operatorname{tr}(I_d)=1,
$$
the values $\frac1d p_i x_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ make up a probability vector. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
\left[\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ix_ix_i^\top\sqrt{x_i^\top\Sigma^{-2}x_i}\right)\right]^{-1}
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\|x_i\|^2\|\Sigma^{-1}x_i\|\right)^{-1}\\
&\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\|x_i\|\ (x_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i)\right)^{-1}\ \text{(Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)}\\
&=\frac1d\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac1d\ p_ix_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i\right)\|x_i\|\right)^{-1}\\
&\le\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac1d\ p_ix_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i\right)\frac1{\|x_i\|}\ \text{(Jensen's inequality)}\\
&\le\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1d\ p_i\|x_i\|\|\Sigma^{-1}x_i\|\frac1{\|x_i\|}\ \text{(Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)}\\
&=\frac1{d^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\|\Sigma^{-1}x_i\|\\
&=\frac1{d^2}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \sqrt{x_i^\top\Sigma^{-2}x_i}\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \sqrt{x_i^\top\Sigma^{-2}x_i}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Sincerely thanks for your thoughtful answer, but the left side of the inequality should be the trace of matrix inverse rather than the reciprocal of the matrix trace. I'm very sorry for my vague expressions of the question.

Comment: Note that ${\rm tr}(A^{-1})\geq \frac{d^2}{{\rm tr}(A)}$. So your thoughtful answer works for the lower bounds of ${\rm tr}(A^{-1})$, but I think it may be close to the final answer.